# Non irreducible primary ideal in $K[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

this is maybe an easy question but I don't see the answer:

I'm trying find a primary ideal in $K[x,y,z]$ non being irreducible (where $K$ is a field)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Q_1, Q_2$ are both $P$-primary, then their intersection $Q_1 \cap Q_2$ is also P-primary. Then $Q_1 \cap Q_2$ is clearly reducible. Use this to find an example.

Comment: great answer! thanks